# Unity Error: Feature 'out variable declaration'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I copied a project from one computer to another, however, when I started Unity I got tons of errors all saying practically the same thing.

Researched online and found nothing. Project worked perfectly fine on a different computer before I moved it.

`` D:/Unity Games/UYW/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.0/Scripts/Runtime/TMPro_UGUI_Private.cs(2028,130): error CS1644: Feature `out variable declaration' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification ``

Shouldn't give any errors.

Comment: Others in the Google-sphere are having this issue as well. Check out this [link](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/PostProcessing/issues/694)

Comment: Sounds like you missed copying some files when you copied your project.

Answer (score 15):

For the error you provided:

Go to `Edit`>`Project Settings`>`Player`, then select `Other Settings` tab and in `Configuration` block try switching `Scripting Runtime Version` to `.NET 4.x Equivalent`.

You can also edit `Assembly-CSharp.csproj` with text editor and change line `<LangVersion>4</LangVersion>` to required C# version, ex. `<LangVersion>6</LangVersion>`

Comment: @briankirst If it solved your problem, please mark my answer as accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: That's great. This should be marked as answer for this question